# Excel shortcut for selection of a large amount of cells

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is there a shortcut to memorize the selection of a determined range of cells?

For example, I have to frequently select from cell `A10` to cell `Y1900`, to sort it in a different way every time.

Is it possible to select this range faster than having to do it manually dragging every time?

Comment: Use the clipboard, open the clipboard, select the range, copy and whenever you need it just click on it in the clipboard to paste it

Comment: I don't have to paste it, just to select it and then sort it by different columns every time

Answer (score 4):

You can use Go to in Editing Group, in the reference write your range:
A10:Y1900
and click ok it will select the range

Another method by defining a Name to the Range:

- Select A10:Y1900
- Write a name in the address bar upper left corner to the left of formula bar and press enter
- When you need to select again, just write the name in the upper left corner of address bar it will select the corresponding range